# How does the Bool from `targetChecked` get turned into an `Action`?

Tags: functional-programming, elm

In the [Elm checkboxes example](http://elm-lang.org/examples/checkboxes) an `Action` is passed to the `tag` argument of the `checkbox` function (lines 51-53).

I don't understand how the type signature for this argument is `(Bool -> Action)` and how on line 69 it's able to use the function composition operator `<<` to transform the `Bool` from `targetChecked` into the complete `Action` type.

EDIT:

This question can be reduced down to "why does the following work?"

```
type Action = Edit Int

do : (Int -> Action) -> Action
do tag = tag(123)

result : Action
result = do(Edit)
```

Comment: It seems to be related to [tagged unions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you define a union type, each tag of the union type becomes a defined value. So when you define:

```
type Action = Tick | NoOp
```

this also defines:

```
Tick : Action
NoOp : Action
```

When the union tag has arguments, it becomes a "constructor", a function:

```
type Action = Edit Int
Edit : Int -> Action
```

(These tags are also used as patterns that you can match on with the `case`-`of` construct. See also the [documentation on the website](http://elm-lang.org/guide/model-the-problem#tagged-unions). )